# Why does .ctor call itself?

Tags: .net-assembly, cil

Why does ctor calls itself and shouldn't this make it loop? I can't quite understand what's going on.

I have looked around online but still can't find an answer.

```
  .method family hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor()
  {
    .maxstack 8
    ldarg.0
    ldstr    asc_203C                   // ""
    stfld    string KGER.BaseConfiguration::_get
    ldarg.0
    **call     instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()**
    nop
    ret
  }
```

Comment: It's calling the parent constructor (`System.Object`) not the one you are in (whatever that is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is chaining (calling) the constructor of your base class (which is `System.Object`).

Even though you do not call it in trivial cases (e.g. empty constructor), the compiler will emit the call as every "part" of your object must be properly constructed.